# Square root of a vector using tryCatch statement

Tags: r

I want to write a function that returns the square root of vector x. I want it to have a tryCatch statement so that when x equals a negative number, it returns x as is and also issues a warning statement that x has negative numbers. The output should say NaN. So far I have this:

```
sqrt_x<-function(x){
if (x<0){
    warning("x is negative")
    }
```

Where do I put the tryCatch statement?

Another attempt at writing this function is here:

```
sqrt_x<- function(x){
tryCatch(
    expr={
     sqrt(any(x))
    },
    warning=function(w){
        message("x is negative")
        print(w)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `tryCatch` statement for that. Use `tryCatch` when you're not sure if R can run something--it might be an error, or it might not. Here, you're writing your own test that tells whether or not it is runnable--the `if` approach is good but you should probably use `if(any(x) < 0)` if you want your function to be vectorized.

Comment: @GregorThomas That's what I was thinking! But for this question, I am required to use the tryCatch statement. I now have 'squareroot<- function(x){
tryCatch(
    expr={
     sqrt(any(x))
    },
    warning=function(w){
        message("x is negative")
        print(w)
        }
    )
}'

Comment: change `expr = sqrt(x), warning = function(w) {warning(sprintf('%d is negative'));NaN}`

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Thank you all for your help

```
sqrt_x<-function(x){
    result <-
    tryCatch({
        sqrt(x)},
             warning = function(w) {
            warning('x contains negative numbers')
                 x
             })
    return (result)
}
```